# Windows Authentication from Local Users and Groups

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, windows-authentication

In Computer->Manage (Computer Management), you can create Windows accounts and assign these users to groups. I'd love to use the same functionality in my web site.

I don't want to use forms authentication because it requires managing an additional username and password.

Is there any way to use this with a Windows-Authenticated MVC 3 website?

For example, if I created a group called "Employees" in Computer Management, is there a way to link 
[Authorize(Roles = "Employees")] to this group? would it be Roles = @"Domain\GroupName"?

This is only necessary for about twenty users with three or so groups. I've come across many who say that Active Directory is the way to go; however, if there is an equally-effective simpler solution, I will take that.

Answer (score 0):

If this is going to run on an intranet with Windows authentication it is okay, but on the internet, although it can be done, don't do it!

Please use forms authentication as it is safer.